# Read files from multiple Folders using SSIS?

Tags: c#, ssis

I am pretty new to SSIS, I have a folder structure, 
Requests -> States -> Roles (Around 5 different folders to 5 kind of roles) -> Activity (Around 30 to 45 activity folders under each Activity) -> Priority (If file is Priority will put under this folder other wise directly under Activity)

1. Can I create one SSIS package to read from any of these activity folders/ Priority folders inside that, and to upload the content to SQL table for each Excel sheet (Created table for all the activities with same fields and unique names and a flag field to update if this is priority)?
2. Or do I need to create SSIS program/script for each Activity?
3. On finish of the upload can I delete/ move the files to a different location?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use ForEach loop container with File enumerator in SSIS

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141724.aspx

Comment: Thank you Lokeshwer, It really helped!!

Answer (score 2):

[For Each Loop Container](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ApyHW9Xj2M4) (YouTube example video)

Comment: Thank you demas, It was really help full!!