# Read multiple xlsx files in a folder and enter a foreach loop in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, file-io, foreach, ssis

I am new to SSIS and would like to know how to read multiple XLSX format files from a folder and enter them in a foreach loop so that they can insert into the database.

I was reviewing this examples:

- [SSIS reading multiple xml files from folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6956409/ssis-reading-multiple-xml-files-from-folder)
- [Read files from multiple Folders using SSIS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470732/read-files-from-multiple-folders-using-ssis)

But I would like to have more details about the foreach loop or if there is another way to upload data files to the database.

Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: Will the Excel Spreadsheets have the *exact* same format? The file names are irrelevant but the structure of the spreadsheet must be consistent if you have any hope of easily consuming Excel.

Comment: SSIS will read both *.xls* and *.xlsx* in a loop, provided that the format of both is the same (meaning the columns don't change).  Based on the question, it also seems you want to read Excel files from other folders?  This would be done with the connection string - so you could clone what you have if those locations will always hold Excel files.

Answer (score 0):

If i understood this correctly,you want to know how to work with Foreach loop

In the foreach loop select enumeration as foreach file enumerator,folder as the folder where the xlsx files exist and in files set it to *.xlsx that way it will pick all xlsx files in the folder then in variable mappings assign the value to a variable lets say varloaction, go to expression on the excel configuration manager and use the varloaction variable to build connection string.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set a for-each loop in SSIS package for reading multiple files having same formats.
Also, if the files are saved in different folders, you need to create separate connections for each folder.

Refer:
For reading multiple XLS files to SQL Server tables:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4165/how-to-read-data-from-multiple-excel-files-with-sql-server-integration-services/

For reading multiple XLSX files to SQL Server tables:

http://www.techbrothersit.com/2013/12/ssis-read-multiple-sheets-from-excel.html